# Rendering Website from zip file via jszip and extraction to localstorage

Tags: javascript, zip

I attempted to figure out a way to render my large (4meg uncompressed) website from a ZIP file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fetch and Open ZIP File</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.6.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="fetchAndOpenZip()">Fetch and Open Website</button>
    <script>
        function fetchAndOpenZip() {
            var zip = new JSZip();
            fetch('https://alcea-wisteria.de/z_files/emoji/alceawis.de-direct.zip')
                .then(function(response) {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        return response.blob();
                    } else {
                        throw new Error('Error: ' + response.status);
                    }
                })
                .then(function(blob) {
                    return zip.loadAsync(blob);
                })
                .then(function() {
                    return zip.file('index.html').async('text');
                })
                .then(function(htmlContent) {
                    var newTab = window.open();
                    var newDoc = newTab.document.open();
                    newDoc.write(htmlContent);
                    newDoc.close();
                    zip.forEach(function(relativePath, zipEntry) {
                        if (htmlContent.includes(relativePath) && !relativePath.endsWith('.php')) {
                            zipEntry.async('text').then(function(content) {
                                var fileType;
                                if (relativePath.endsWith('.js')) {
                                    fileType = 'script';
                                } else if (relativePath.endsWith('.css')) {
                                    fileType = 'style';
                                } else if (relativePath.endsWith('.html')) {
                                    fileType = 'html';
                                } else {
                                    fileType = 'asset';
                                }
                                if (fileType === 'script') {
                                    var script = newDoc.createElement('script');
                                    script.textContent = content;
                                    newDoc.body.appendChild(script);
                                } else if (fileType === 'style') {
                                    var style = newDoc.createElement('style');
                                    style.textContent = content;
                                    newDoc.head.appendChild(style);
                                } else if (fileType === 'html') {
                                    var newDiv = newDoc.createElement('div');
                                    newDiv.innerHTML = content;
                                    newDoc.body.appendChild(newDiv);
                                } else if (fileType === 'asset') {
                                    // Create a Blob object from the content
                                    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
                                    var reader = new FileReader();
                                    reader.onload = function(event) {
                                        // Create a data URL for the asset file
                                        var dataUrl = event.target.result;
                                        var mimeType = zipEntry.name.endsWith('.png') ? 'image/png' : 'image/jpeg';
                                        var img = newDoc.createElement('img');
                                        img.src = dataUrl;
                                        img.type = mimeType;
                                        newDoc.body.appendChild(img);
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Sadly it only loads parts of it. Is there a mistake in my code?

I tried changing the code to iterate files in the ZIP. Sadly it won't read them all and only renders the `index.html` with most assets missing.

None of the suggestions online manage to load the website properly.

I even wrote a [reference mapper](https://codepen.io/ryedai1/pen/xxBNoBK), but it seems superfluous as I would have some loop it on every call.